# how to call from php mongodb javascript function?

Tags: php, mongodb

**in php i call mongodb javascript function start()**

```
$username="root"; 

$password="root";

$mongo_uri="mongodb://".$username.":".$password."@localhost";

$connection = new MongoClient( $mongo_uri );

$db = $connection->test;

$response = $db->execute("start()");

print_r($response);
```

**as a result of getting**

```
 Array
    (

        [ok] => 0

        [errmsg] => unauthorized

    )
```

$username + $password + $mongo_uri - right, and $db give ok connect ,

but get an error unauthorized on `$response = $db->execute("start()");`

**how to call from php mongodb function start()?**

Answer (score 0):

The [**`execute()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php) method here is implemented as a wrapper around the [**`db.eval()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) method for MongoDB. So presumably you are referring to some server side JavaScript method you have loaded on the server start.

As shown in the [authentication roles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/) manual page, [eval](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#combined-access) requires special privileges that likely have not been granted to the account you are using to authenticate with. This is probably a **good** thing as for general CRUD operations the account used should not have those privilege levels. If anything this sort of operation should only be used on it's own privileged connection.

Executing server side JavaScript is generally not a very good idea for production systems, and if your function is actually something rather trivial then it is best to re-implement this in your native library code.

So please note the **warnings** on th[**`db.eval()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) manual page, and also note that even with the correct permissions assigned, you will not be able to run this command on a sharded cluster environment.

Finally, also see the [**`MongoCode`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocode.php) class for a generally better way to define JavaScript calls if you absolutely need them.

Comment: i created admin with all possible privileges 
the error persists

Comment: @user3495941 are you possibly running on a sharded cluster as was mentioned?

Comment: i work on heroku, i created admin with all possible privileges roles: [ "read", "readWrite", "dbAdmin", "userAdmin", "clusterAdmin", "readAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase", "userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase" ]
the error persists

Answer (score 0):

eval() requires special privileges.

Its use is so discouraged that you need to create the role yourself.

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval